# How should I refactor switch statements like this (Switching on type) to be more OO?

Tags: object-oriented, refactoring, switch-statement

I'm seeing some code like this in our code base, and want to refactor it:

(Typescript psuedocode follows):

```
class EntityManager{

private findEntityForServerObject(entityType:string, serverObject:any):IEntity {

    var existingEntity:IEntity = null;

    switch(entityType) {
      case Types.UserSetting:
            existingEntity = this.getUserSettingByUserIdAndSettingName(serverObject.user_id, serverObject.setting_name);
                break;

        case Types.Bar:
            existingEntity = this.getBarByUserIdAndId(serverObject.user_id, serverObject.id);
            break;

        //Lots more case statements here...
    }
    return existingEntity;
 }

 }
```

The downsides of switching on type are self-explanatory. Normally, when switching behavior based on type, I try to push the behavior into subclasses so that I can reduce this to a single method call, and let polymorphism take care of the rest.

However, the following two things are giving me pause:

1) I don't want to couple the serverObject with the class that is storing all of these objects. It doesn't know where to look for entities of a certain type. And unfortunately, the identity of a type of ServerObject varies with the type of ServerObject. (So sometimes it's just an ID, other times it's a combination of an id and a uniquely identifying string, etc). And this behavior doesn't belong down there on those subclasses. It is the responsibility of the EntityManager and its delegates.

2) In this case, I can't modify the ServerObject classes since they're plain old data objects. It should be mentioned that I've got other instances of the above method that take a parameter like "IEntity" and proceed to do almost the same thing (but slightly modify the name of the methods they're calling to get the identity of the entity). So, we might have:

```
        case Types.Bar:
            existingEntity = this.getBarByUserIdAndId(entity.getUserId(), entity.getId());
            break;
```

So in that case, I *can* change the entity interface and subclasses, but this isn't behavior that belongs in that class.

So, I *think* that points me to some sort of map. So eventually I will call:

```
private findEntityForServerObject(entityType:string, serverObject:any):IEntity {

    return aMapOfSomeSort[entityType].findByServerObject(serverObject);

}

private findEntityForEntity(someEntity:IEntity):IEntity {
    return aMapOfSomeSort[someEntity.entityType].findByEntity(someEntity);
}
```

Which means I need to register some sort of strategy classes/functions at runtime with this map. And again, I darn well better remember to register one for each my my types, or I'll get a runtime exception.

Is there a better way to refactor this? I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

Comment: Switching on type isn't inherently bad. There's a trade-off there - it's easier to add new functions that operate on that set of types (just write a new function) but harder to add new types (every existing function needs to be fixed). With objects you have the converse - it's easy to add new types (just implement every method) but harder to add new methods (must fix every existing class.)

Comment: Looking at the sample, couldn't you just use overloading, passing an actual type instead of a string? Your design is kind of setting off some alarms; there is code up above deciding what type string to pass in, but why defer that decision? Instead of choosing a type string up above, why not just invoke the appropriate method? In a language with function pointers, you could select a function instead of a string. But I'm wondering why you need to defer the actual execution instead of just calling it up front & keeping your call stack small.

Comment: @Doval: Very good observations. I would add that using a switch statement is not object-oriented. The object-oriented solution is to use dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Thanks - @Doval, one of the other downsides to switching on types is that I might forget to account for one of my types, but if I enforce it by making it a part of an explicit interface, there are ways I can ensure I won't forget it.

Comment: @RobY, the code that calls this is not aware at compile time what type it is being called on. In this case the string is coming from the incoming serverObject, and those are untyped plain old javascript objects.

Comment: @Giorgio, that was original point I wanted to make - dynamic dispatch felt more OO to me.

Comment: @Taytay See [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159804/how-do-you-encode-algebraic-data-types-in-a-c-or-java-like-language) for how to handle type switching in a safe way, especially [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/228125/116461). It handles the case where you want to switch on 2 choices, but is easily expanded to any number of choices. The only change I'd make is to give the superclass (e.g. `Either`) a private constructor and make the subclasses (e.g. `Left` and `Right`) sealed inner classes so no one can add more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you start switching by type (or providing if's based on type), then you're going against the OO model. In a good OO design, the implementation class should be hidden from the calling code.

(That said, there are times when it's easier to do a quick instanceof, but I try to make it rare).

Polymorphism is the answer here.

Really, what you're doing is calling some common action on some classes. So spin off an interface that defines that common call, and then reference the objects through that interface.

In other words, whenever I see myself writing "if xxx.class" or "xxx instanceof" or "switch (xxx.class)", I ask myself is there's a common interface I can pull out.

Now, it can be tricky. If the different classes require different parameters, you might need to use some sort of Builder pattern. It can get complicated.

But the short answer, anyway, is: if you're switching or iffing based on class type, you should really be using polymorphism instead.

Comment: As stated in my [other comment](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/242899/how-should-i-refactor-switch-statements-like-this-switching-on-type-to-be-more#comment487153_242899), it's not strictly true that this is bad. The REAL issue is that there are cases where the values of a given type can come in more than one "shape". For example, a binary tree can be empty, or it can contain a value and two other trees. A cartesian point may come in rectangular coordinates, or polar. However, mainstream languages don't provide the means for "classifying" values of a type, so you end up...

Comment: ...having to fake it using subtypes instead. Classifying values and pattern matching on them is very common in functional languages, where this functionality comes built-in. E.g. In Standard ML I can define `datatype Point = Rectangular of {x: real, y: real} | Polar of {magnitude: real, angle: real}` and then switch on whether a value was constructed using the `Rectangular` or `Polar` constructor.

Comment: I was going to delete my answer, because I don't think it's quite responsive, but I'll hang onto it for the discussion. Type checking weakens OO, because the compiler and runtime engine is supposed to handle that for you. You end up doing dynamic dispatch manually. So I have to disagree -- in strict OO, it is a bad thing. In practical OO, though, sometimes it's better than the alternative.

Comment: Also, the question is tagged "object-oriented" so I can stiff-arm the functional guys and just say no :P

Comment: True, doing `instanceof` weakens type checking, but again, this is simply an unfortunate side effect of mainstream languages not providing a real mechanism for classifying values that doesn't involve new types. But there's type-safe ways to encode this kind of classification: see [this Stack Overflow question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159804/how-do-you-encode-algebraic-data-types-in-a-c-or-java-like-language). In addition to that, the Visitor Pattern is also a poor attempt at pulling this kind of classification and switching off.

Comment: As a real, non-academic example of where this sort of thing would be necessary, suppose your application serializes/deserializes some JSON and there's only 3 valid configurations of fields. If you refuse to classify the values into the 3 kinds, you'll end up creating one monolithic class that contains the union of all fields of all 3 configurations, and adding an enum for figuring out which of the 3 configurations this value has. Then the burden of reading the right fields falls squarely on the programmer.

Comment: No one said OO was good. :)

Comment: The JSON example is actually interesting, because it's a case of mapping a dynamically-type language (javascript) into a statically typed language (e.g. java). So that's an example of trying to do a downcast of AnyClass in a imaginary hierarchy with several possible concrete subclasses. In a dynamically-typed OO, you'd use duck typing and drive on. In a statically-typed language, you're going to have to do some scrambling. But I think that's more of a conflict between dynamic vs. static typing.

Comment: @Doval: As you pointed out, functional languages use pattern matching. Indeed, pattern-matching is the functional approach, dynamic dispatching the object-oriented approach.

Comment: @Giorgio I feel those distinctions are fairly artificial. You can do OO in a functional language - an object/interface is merely a record of functions. You would do this in a functional language wherever an open type hierarchy makes sense and not do it whenever it doesn't make sense. An open type hierarchy is pointless for my `Point` example because in practice there's a finite number of *useful* representations of points. You will most likely not be adding new varieties in practice.

Comment: I am not saying that you cannot use if's in a certain way in an object-oriented language. I am saying that dynamic dispatching is an essential idea of object-orientation, and using it is a typical object-oriented solution. Analogously, pattern matching is made possible by the use of algebraic data types, which are an important idea in functional languages. So, these distinctions are not artificial, they are based on core ideas of the two paradigms.

Comment: @Giorgio That's a fair point.

Comment: RobY, We're in philosophical agreement here, and I was looking for an OO answer. :) After reading the discussion, I do think that _part_ of the issue is that I'm working in Typescript, which adds some static type constructs to Javascript, so I'm straddling the line. Maybe I shouldn't let this type-check bother me so much in this case, or should look for ways to limit the # of times I have to do this. The only ways out I see involve a lot more code for seemingly negligible benefit. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I would map between entityTypes and an object that knows what to do with that entity type. So you might have something like

```
private findEntityForServerObject(entityType:string, serverObject:any):IEntity {
    EntityFinder entityFinder = EntityFinder.getForEntity(entityType);
    return entityFinder.find(serverObject);
}
```

You will then be pushing the switch into EntityFinder which will have a static method along the following lines

```
class EntityFinder {
    public static EntityFinder getForEntity(String entityType) {
        switch (entityType) {
            case Types.UserSetting:
               return new UserSettingsFinder();
            case Types.Bar:
               return new BarSettingsFinder();
            default:
               // Possibly better than a null pointer
               return new UnknownSettingsFinder(); 
        }
    }
}
```

If you introduce a new type, you will have to remember to include it in the switch but hopefully, you will only have one place to do this.

Comment: By the way, is this ActionScript? I wasn't sure what language I was working in so the syntax may not be 100%.

Comment: Thanks @PhilDin - it's actually TypeScript. (Similar to ActionScript). The advantage of your approach is that you limit the switch statement to one place, but I still have the possibility of forgetting to create a finder for a type. Not a massive deal, but would prefer that not to be an issue. I also have to create additional classes for each of my types, so I feel like this might be a lot more code/ceremony than I wanted.