# Remove duplicated switch statements caused by not knowing type at compile time of opencv matrix?

Tags: c++, refactoring, qt, switch-statement, c++14

I have a situation that occurs 5 times in my code, and continues to grow.  Basically I have the same switch statement structure every time I need to perform an operation that involves my matrix and its type (which is set dynamically at runtime from files and user input). Here is one such example:

```
//QTableWidget m_matrix_table;
//cv::Mat m_matrix;
MatrixBoxWidget::MatrixBoxWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(
        parent) {
     ...
     connect(m_matrix_table, &QTableWidget::cellChanged, this,
             &MatrixBoxWidget::updateMatrixValue);
     ...
}

void MatrixBoxWidget::updateMatrixValue(int row, int column) {
    QTableWidgetItem item = m_matrix_table->item(row, column);
    QVariant qvariant = item->data(0);
    int type = m_matrix.type();
    switch (type) {
        case CV_8U:
            m_matrix.at<std::uint8_t>(row, column)
                    = qvariant.value<std::uint8_t>();
            break;
        case CV_8S:
            m_matrix.at<std::int8_t>(row, column)
                    = qvariant.value<std::int8_t>();
            break;
        case CV_16U:
            m_matrix.at<std::uint16_t>(row, column)
                    = qvariant.value<std::uint16_t>();
            break;
        case CV_16S:
            m_matrix.at<std::int16_t>(row, column)
                    = qvariant.value<std::int16_t>();
            break;
        case CV_32S:
            m_matrix.at<std::int32_t>(row, column)
                    = qvariant.value<std::int32_t>();
            break;
        case CV_32F:
            m_matrix.at<float>(row, column)
                    = qvariant.value<float>();
            break;
        case CV_64F:
            m_matrix.at<double>(row, column)
                    = qvariant.value<double>();
            break;
        default:
            assert((false, "unknown type format"));
            break;
    }

}
```

usually the function signatures (or what ever else I decide to do in the switch cases) are homogenous except for the types in most circumstances, **I'm only aiming to fix these cases**.

Opencv uses these integers to change the type of a matrix.  This is what I'm switching on.   What can I do to mitigate this? Or is this kind of boiler plate necessary?  Template functions that take another function don't appear to work since they would require all the templates versions of the function anyway, which doesn't get rid of the boiler plate code.

EDIT:

The marked duplicate has actually zero to do with my question.  There's not a single template mentioned in either answer, and neither solves my problem.

This is what I'd like to do:

`foo<T>(int type, std::function bar)` where bar would be templated inside of foo, but that is clearly not possible with current C++ semantics. **the problem isn't that I'm using switch statements, its that the pattern is homogeneous across multiple use cases with the same cases**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I refactor switch statements like this (Switching on type) to be more OO?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/242899/how-should-i-refactor-switch-statements-like-this-switching-on-type-to-be-more)

Comment: @gnat most definitely not,  the fact that it has switch in the name doesn't mean it helps me (the answers are completely irrelevant to my needs) though it would be nice if there was a duplicate. I'm not looking to put a giant class hierarchy to "solve" this that would just make the code not clean.  I need  away to have the structure of the switch statement, and also input templated functions into ideally like so: `foo<T>(type, bar)` where bar is templated inside of foo.

Comment: Can you template you whole code (or at least everything that's called once you know the type you are using)?

Comment: @Caleth No. the type is only known at runtime, and all the functions that are called with these switch statements are called at runtime, the type can only be known at runtime (I mention this previously, because its defined through UI via user manually selecting type or by loading a separate file).  For example, there's a UI function to update the internal matrix with the display widget  In order to update the matri I need to set values in the opencv matrix.  The only way to set values from a opencv matrix is to also know the type along side it, it is a templated function (`at<T>`)

Comment: @gnat I should mention it isn't just the class hierarchy thing, the question regardless is just not useful and the answers don't address any of my concerns.

Comment: What I mean is, you could reduce it from 5 places to one place. `int main() { auto type = getType(); switch (type) { case CV_8U: new_main<uint_8t>(); ... } };`

Comment: @Caleth No, there is more than one entry point in the sense you are talking about, this is UI code, type needs to be derived for from separate instances.  events fire off and cause different things to need to happen.  For example, the user can edit the type, the user can load a matrix, the rows can be edited (and type must be maintained) or cols must be edited.  All of those happen independently from one another, and are initiated from the UI when the user so chooses.  Thus separate switches need to exist for each.

Comment: @snb: It's not clear to me what the relationship between `type`, `m_matrix`, and `qvariant` are. Does `m_matrix` *know* that it stores a particular type? Does `qvariant`? Or is that something which this action is assigning them? If there is a type-mismatch, is the fault of that `type` or `m_matrix`? Is the type of `m_matrix` set, or can it be changed? And if it can be changed, when can it be changed? And so forth. There are a number of possible solutions, but without understanding the code *behind* all of this, it's not clear which one is appropriate.

Comment: @NicolBolas It sounds like there are a bunch of type-erasing containers, which (hopefully) have been filled with homogeneous objects. It may still be possible to write it in terms of non-type erasing containers

Comment: @NicolBolas  It is an opencv thing, `m_matrix` is a `cv::Mat` the type of the values in a matrix is interpreted pretty much, defined by an integral value for type.  you can query the type via `.type()`.  qvariant came from retrieving the value from the UI, i've updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: @Caleth yes all objects in both the UI table and m_matrix are homogeneous.

Comment: @NicolBolas I've added more context, tell me if I need to add more

Comment: I'd be tempted to drop `cv::Mat` for `cv::Mat_<T>`, then template `MatrixBoxWidget<T>` etc. At the point where the user wants to change type, create a whole new UI, and convert the members as appropriate. A plus side will be compile time notification if you miss a conversion

Comment: @Caleth I'm not sure that would work for my specific case, QT doesn't do Q_Objects and templates IIRC, but I think it may be work while for you to post an answer about that for future reference (it doesn't have to be very specific).   I might be able to bypass the Q_OBJECT thing via encapsulating it in another widget which swaps MatrixBoxWidgets<T> and links events to it. It wouldn't be pretty though.

Comment: You can have a abstract `MatrixBoxWidgetBase` with all the signal handling and a `MatrixBoxWidget<T>` concrete subclass. Or have a templated pimpl for your matrix UI

Comment: @Caleth templates = no Q_OBJECT = no signals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80772/discussion-between-caleth-and-snb).

Comment: @Caleth Can you please write up your solution in an answer? I'd hate for your ideas to get nuked by comment deletion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, if you have the same kind of code multiple times, meaning switch on type-code and then use identical code with that type,  how about using a template and generic lambda?

```
template <class F>
auto do_typed(int type, F f) {
    switch(type) {
    case CV_8U:  return f(std::enable_if<true, std::uint8_t>());
    case CV_8S:  return f(std::enable_if<true, std::int8_t>());
    case CV_16U: return f(std::enable_if<true, std::uint16_t>());
    case CV_16S: return f(std::enable_if<true, std::int16_t>());
    case CV_32S: return f(std::enable_if<true, std::int32_t>());
    case CV_32F: return f(std::enable_if<true, float>());
    case CV_64F: return f(std::enable_if<true, double>());
    }
    assert(false);
}
```

And use it like:

```
do_typed(m_matrix.type(), [&](auto x){
    using T = typename decltype(x)::type;
    m_matrix.at<T>(row, column) = qvariant<T>();
});
```

I'm using the trivial type `std::enable_if<true, T>` to signal the intended type because it is always a trivial empty type, thus not imposing any restrictions on what can be conveyed.

Also, if you have more type-lists and the type-codes are consecutive, it can be easily generalized.

Comment: Oh shit, I didn't even know this was possible, I think this is exactly what I was looking for.